# go back to previous row when iterating through a pandas data frame using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a dataframe similar to the below:

```
data = {'part': ['c', 'c', 'c', 'p', 'p', 
'p', 'p', 'p'], 'index': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'text': 
['a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], 'class': [[1,0,0], 
[0,1,0], [1,1,0], None , None , None  , None , None]}


data = pd.DataFrame(data)

data
```

I am trying to iterate through this data frame to display the strings of the column "text" to users so that they can name these strings. I also want to provide users the chance to return to previously presented strings in case they change their mind and need to rename previous strings. How can I achieve this goal? I am trying the below code:

```
for n, c in enumerate(data['text']):
    a = input(f"Enter labels for the text or enter 2 to go back to 
        previous: \n\n{c}\n\n: ")
    if a == '2':
        idx = n - 1
        c = c[idx]
    



IndexError                                Traceback (most recent 
call last)
<ipython-input-59-ca3c4aa6f370> in <module>
      3   if a == '2':
      4     idx = n - 1
----> 5     c = c[idx]
      6 
      7 

IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: maybe you should use `.shift(1)` to create new column with value from previous row - and you will have both values in the same row - and then you can try to do it without `for`-loop but using `.apply()`. OR you should first check `if idx >= 0`. OR you should skip first row (because it doesn't have previous row) and use `data['text'][1:]`

Comment: `c` is text from cell, not dataframe. You should use `c = data['text'][idx]`. Other method is to always keep `previous = c` and late you can use `c = previous`

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: BTW: sometimes you may have dataframe which doesn't use consecutive numbers as indexes and it can be safrer to use `for index, value in data['text'].iterrows()` and remeber `previous_index = index` and in next loop use `data['text'][previous_index]`. And before loop you can set `previous_index = None` and in loo check `if previous_index is not None`

Comment: you probably want a while loop as opposed to for ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go back to previous row then you should use `while`-loop and manually change `index += 1` or `index -= 1` and get `text = data['text'][index]` or `row = data.loc[index]`

But all this will work only if indexes use  consecutive numbers.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'part': ['c', 'c', 'c', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p'],
    'index': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'text': ['a','b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
    'class': [[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [1,1,0], None , None , None  , None , None]
}

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data['label'] = ''
print(data)

index = 0

while index < len(data):
    row = data.loc[index]
        
    print("Enter labels for the text or enter 2 to go back to previous:")
    print()
    print('index:', index)
    print('text :', row['text'])
    print('label:', row['label'])
    print()
    
    label = input(": ")
    
    if label == '2':
        index -= 1  # go to previous
        if index < 0:
            print('There is no previous row')    
            index = 0
    else:
        #row['label'] = label
        data.loc[index, 'label'] = label
        index += 1  # go to next
    
print(data)
```